# Transfer learning model running on inference does not learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm doing a species classification task from kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/yum-or-yuck-butterfly-mimics-2022/overview). I decided to use transfer learning to tackle this problem since there aren't that many images. The model is as follows:

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
base_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(
    input_shape=(224,224,3),
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet")
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation="softmax")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
```

As per the guidelines when doing transfer learning:https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/, I'm freezing the resnet layers and training the model on inference only (training=False). However, the results show that the model is not learning properly. Convergence doesn't seem like it will be possible even after nearly 200 epochs:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics="accuracy",
)
stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    min_delta=0.0001,
    patience=20,
    restore_best_weights=True
)
history = model.fit(train_generator,
          validation_data = val_generator,
          epochs = 200,
         callbacks=[stop_early])

22/22 [==============================] - 19s 442ms/step - loss: 1.9317 - accuracy: 0.1794 - val_loss: 1.8272 - val_accuracy: 0.1618
Epoch 2/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 398ms/step - loss: 1.8250 - accuracy: 0.1882 - val_loss: 1.7681 - val_accuracy: 0.2197
Epoch 3/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 402ms/step - loss: 1.7927 - accuracy: 0.2294 - val_loss: 1.7612 - val_accuracy: 0.2139
Epoch 4/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 424ms/step - loss: 1.7930 - accuracy: 0.2000 - val_loss: 1.7640 - val_accuracy: 0.2139
Epoch 5/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 391ms/step - loss: 1.7872 - accuracy: 0.2132 - val_loss: 1.7489 - val_accuracy: 0.3121
Epoch 6/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 389ms/step - loss: 1.7700 - accuracy: 0.2574 - val_loss: 1.7378 - val_accuracy: 0.2543
Epoch 7/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 396ms/step - loss: 1.7676 - accuracy: 0.2353 - val_loss: 1.7229 - val_accuracy: 0.3064
Epoch 8/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 427ms/step - loss: 1.7721 - accuracy: 0.2353 - val_loss: 1.7225 - val_accuracy: 0.2948
Epoch 9/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 399ms/step - loss: 1.7522 - accuracy: 0.2588 - val_loss: 1.7267 - val_accuracy: 0.2948
Epoch 10/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 395ms/step - loss: 1.7434 - accuracy: 0.2735 - val_loss: 1.7151 - val_accuracy: 0.2948
Epoch 11/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 391ms/step - loss: 1.7500 - accuracy: 0.2632 - val_loss: 1.7083 - val_accuracy: 0.3064
Epoch 12/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 425ms/step - loss: 1.7307 - accuracy: 0.2721 - val_loss: 1.6899 - val_accuracy: 0.3179
Epoch 13/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 407ms/step - loss: 1.7439 - accuracy: 0.2794 - val_loss: 1.7045 - val_accuracy: 0.2948
Epoch 14/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 404ms/step - loss: 1.7376 - accuracy: 0.2706 - val_loss: 1.7118 - val_accuracy: 0.2659
Epoch 15/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 419ms/step - loss: 1.7588 - accuracy: 0.2647 - val_loss: 1.6684 - val_accuracy: 0.3237
Epoch 16/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 394ms/step - loss: 1.7289 - accuracy: 0.2824 - val_loss: 1.6733 - val_accuracy: 0.3064
Epoch 17/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 387ms/step - loss: 1.7184 - accuracy: 0.2809 - val_loss: 1.7185 - val_accuracy: 0.2659
Epoch 18/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 408ms/step - loss: 1.7242 - accuracy: 0.2765 - val_loss: 1.6961 - val_accuracy: 0.2717
Epoch 19/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 424ms/step - loss: 1.7218 - accuracy: 0.2853 - val_loss: 1.6757 - val_accuracy: 0.3006
Epoch 20/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 396ms/step - loss: 1.7248 - accuracy: 0.2882 - val_loss: 1.6716 - val_accuracy: 0.3064
Epoch 21/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 401ms/step - loss: 1.7134 - accuracy: 0.2838 - val_loss: 1.6666 - val_accuracy: 0.2948
Epoch 22/200
22/22 [==============================] - 9s 393ms/step - loss: 1.7140 - accuracy: 0.2941 - val_loss: 1.6427 - val_accuracy: 0.3064
```

I need to unfreeze the layers and turn off inference in order for the model to learn. I tested the same scenario with EfficientNet and the same thing happened. Finally, I also used Xception, and freezing the layers and running with inference was fine. So it seems they behave differently, even though they all have batchnorm layers.

I'm not understanding what is going on here. Why would I need to turn inference off? Could anyone have a clue about this?

EDIT:
results from Resnet50:

[image]

results from Xception:

[image]

Comment: What makes you say its not learning? Loss is slowly reducing and accuracy is slowly increasing. You're using dropout which will slow convergence but make the model perform better on the validation/test set. What's the performance on that like?

Comment: I mispoke . It is learning, but performance is very poor. As per the plots the resnet model has very sudden drops and progress seems to be plateuing. In contrast, Xception performs quite well and converges quite fast. The number of parameters is similar so Im not too sure what is happening. Why would I need to turn inference off for the resnet to converge faster and perform much better?

Comment: Are the Imagenet weights for resnet50 actually useful for this application? It might be worth trying comparative runs (with all layers trainable) with weights="None" and weights = "Imagenet"